# What is the rebus

Tags: rebus

What is the meaning of rebus? Hope find out its meaning.

[image]

Clue: It is an English phrase.

Answer (score 17):

I think it's:

> **"Cut right to the chase"**, or simply **"Cut to the chase"**: get to the point without wasting time.

Because the picture is:

> Cut. Right [to]. Chess.

Comment: That isn’t proper chess though, the white king and queen are on the wrong spots.

Comment: @Bass It might have come from [here](https://pixabay.com/en/chessboard-chess-board-game-29630/). Blame the user "Clker-Free-Vector-Images" on that site. Their icon is a fish. I don't think fish know how to play chess.

Answer (score 8):

I think it might be

> "Cut to pieces"

Answer (score 2):

My guess is...

> cutting a check

Since...

> you are literally cutting the checkerboard pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

> [Split down the middle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/divide-split-sth-down-the-middle), meaning divide into equal parts.

Explanation:

> Scissors are used to cut/divide/split things. The arrow is pointing at the middle of the chess board, which if cut would divide it into two equal halves.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Cut across the board, meaning cuts (e.g. in pay) across all levels of an organisation

Answer (score 1):

> Split your sides

reference for those who have never heard the phrase:

> [reference](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/split-your-sides)